# Tricky jQuery DOM Manipulation (Wrapping text)

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have some HTML as such:

```
<span class="number">1.</span>Lorem ipsum dolor. <span class="special">Sit amet.</span> Consectur adipisicing elit. 
<span class="number">2.</span>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

What I want is this:

```
<span class="point"><span class="number">1.</span><span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor. <span class="bar">Sit amet.</span> Consectur adipisicing elit.</span></span>
<span class="point"><span class="number">2.</span><span class="text">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span></span>
```

Basically, each "number" span indicates the start of a bullet point, which runs either until the next "number" span or until the end of the HTML if there are no more "number" spans. Within the points, there may be additional HTML tags as well as plain text. I want to wrap each bullet point in a span, and also wrap the text within the bullet point in a span. Unfortunately, this looks like it might be a pain.

Any idea how I can go about this with jQuery (or some other solution even)?

Edit: Figured it out. jQuery has a `.nextUntil()` function that's appropriate here: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/
After that, the wrapping can be done using `.wrap()`: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Edit again: Actually, I think the `.nextUntil()` function only deals with tag nodes and not text nodes. :(

Comment: I'm sure you haven't created this markup, but using an `<ol>` would be the right choice...

Comment: I agree, it doesn't solve your problem but it looks as if using the correct markup to create the list would make your life a lot easier here.

Comment: Yep, not my markup. Also, they're not really bullet points, but I kind of abstracted the problem to that for simplicity. `<span>` is in fact the right tag.

Comment: @Chris An `ol` has no bullet points, it does exactly the same as your markup.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but you'll just have to take my word on it. I know HTML. `<ol>` is a reasonable suggestion for the abstracted problem I've posed, but it's not appropriate in the actual situation. Anyway, whatever HTML tag is used is not really consequential to the problem. You can imagine `<span class="number">1.</span>` substituted with `<span class="foo">Blahblahblah</span>` if you want. I'm using `<span>` to keep all the tags the same since that may be consequential.

Comment: FWIW, I guess the actual question is basically about using tags as delimiters for jQuery selections in a kind of weird specific way. The actual wrapping isn't the problem.

Comment: @Chris Was just suggesting because it would make your life much easier, with this markup, to be honest, I'm stuck :). jQuery is not really clever with simple textnodes.

Comment: If I were writing to standards-based browsers, I'd use [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:range) objects to solve this.  Google doesn't seem to show jQuery encapsulating these, but that doesn't surprise me since IE 6/7 don't support them and I don't know about versions 8 or 9.

Comment: @Chris "each "number" span indicates the start of a bullet point," That's what your HTML is represting. So clearly you should be using an `ul` or an `ol`. Semantic HTML please or describe what your HTML is supposed to do more accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works...

```
var point = $('<span class="point" />');

$('body').contents().each(function() {

    var element = $(this);

    if (point.children().length > 0 && element.is('span.number')) {
        $('body').append(point);
        point = $('<span class="point" />');
    } 

    point.append(element);

})

$('body').append(point);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/PFrka/).

Comment: There is one extra `.point` in the beginning, you can avoid it by checking `point.children().length > 0` before appending+recreating it.

Comment: @SalmanA: You are correct, and I did that first with `index` but removed it for some reason. Cheers.